# Text file Buffered Reader

Tags: java, text, bufferedreader

How would I change the befferedreader in my code to Scanner because i'm not allowed use BufferedReader?? or is it even possible ??

```
public static void Option3Method() throws IOException
{ 
   FileReader fr = new FileReader("wordlist.txt");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
   String s;
   String words[]=new String[500];
   String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word to search for");
   while ((s=br.readLine())!=null)
   { 
     int indexfound=s.indexOf(word);
     if (indexfound>-1)
     { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word was found");
     }
     else if (indexfound<-1)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word was not found");}
     }
     fr.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`FileReader fr = new FileReader("wordlist.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);`

with

`Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("wordlist.txt"));`

And replace

`while ((s=br.readLine())!=null)
{`

with

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {

            s=scan.nextLine();
        }
```

Comment: That gives me an error then saying String s was not defined??

Comment: So declare the variable named 's'. I have not given you completely baked code that you can directly use in your code. It is just a sample which indicates which part of the existing code needs to be changed and with what.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Scanner class you can see that it has a constructor that takes a File, which in turn can be instantiated with a String path. The Scanner class has a similar method to readLine() namely nextLine().

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [constructor of scanner that takes a file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) then read the lines using that scanner using [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29). To check whether there are more line to read use [hasNextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test it but it should work.

```
public static void Option3Method() throws IOException
{ 
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("wordlist.txt"));
   String s;
   String words[]=new String[500];
   String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a word to search for");
   while (scan.hasNextLine())
   { 
     s = scan.nextLine();
     int indexfound=s.indexOf(word);
     if (indexfound>-1)
     { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word was found");
     }
     else if (indexfound<-1)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word was not found");}
     }
   }
}
```